# Как сделать функцию, которая активируется при нажатии на последовательность клавиш

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать функцию, которая выполняется при нажатии на определенную последовательность клавиш? 
Например:

> <kbd>ВВЕРХ</kbd> + <kbd>ВВЕРХ</kbd> + <kbd>ВНИЗ</kbd> + <kbd>ВНИЗ</kbd> + <kbd>ВЛЕВО</kbd> + <kbd>ВПРАВО</kbd> + <kbd>Пробел</kbd>

Comment: http://bfy.tw/8fJ7 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// Секретная функция
function secret(){
  alert('Konami code has been entered!');
}

// Преобразуем массив из лево-право в коды клавиш
function transform(input){
  let map = {
    'лево': 37,
    'верх': 38,
    'право': 39,
    'низ': 40,
    'пробел': 32
  },
      newArr = [];
  
  input.forEach(name => {
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    
    if(name in map)
      newArr.push(map[name]);
  });
  
  if(input.length !== newArr.length)
    throw new Error(`Допускаются только следующие значения: "${Object.keys(map).join`", "`}"!`);
  else
    return newArr;
}

/**
 * Отслеживает комбинации
 *
 * @param {Array}    comb Массив последовательности значений: лево, право, верх, низ, пробел
 * @param {Function} fn   Секретная функция, будет вызвана при вводе последовательности
 * @param {Boolean}  perm Более одного раза слушать? По умолчанию - нет
 */
function konami(comb, fn, perm = false){
  let keys = transform(comb), // Создаём массив ключей
      pointer = 0, // Указатель на текущий ключ
      check = e => {
        // Если введённый код равен ожидаемой клавише
        if(e.keyCode === keys[pointer]){
          // То проверяем достигли мы конца или нет
          if(keys.length === ++pointer){
            if(!perm)
              document.removeEventListener('keydown', check);
            pointer = 0;
            fn();
          }
        }else{
          // Если ввели что-то другое - сбрасываем указатель на начало
          pointer = 0;
        }
      };
  
  document.addEventListener('keydown', check);
}



konami(['лево', 'право', 'низ'], secret);
konami(['лево', 'пробел', 'низ'], e => console.info('Ура, я всегда буду выполняться!'), true);
```

Comment: бредок какой-то в примере.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, в каком смысле?